# Convert an Integer into chunks and get the max and min of each using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a system that will process 100 records at a time. The number of records that are available can be 1..n. I need to chunk the data into ranges then get the max and min of those ranges and then process using javascript.  I am not sure how to accomplish this.

```
    var n = 500;  
    var process_max  = 100;
    var number_of_times_to_process = Math.ceil(n/process_max) // 5
```

so in this case there will be 5 ranges it would need to process

```
        1 to 100
        101 to 200
        201 to 300
        301 to 400
        401 to 500


    for( i = 0; i < number_of_times_to_process; i++){
       function processranges(max, min) {
       //do something
       }
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like you have the basic setup, what do you need a hand with?

Comment: What do you mean by "at a time"? Do you want to do this asynchronously, with a timeout between the chunks? Or just need the logical process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 500;  
var process_max  = 100;
var number_of_times_to_process = Math.ceil(n/process_max) // 5

for( i = 0; i < number_of_times_to_process; i++) {
    var min = i * process_max + 1;
    var max = min + process_max - 1;
    processranges(min, max);
}

function processranges(min, max) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to increase min and max by 100 each time?
Like so?

```
var min, max, n = 500, process_max = 100;

for(min = 1, max = process_max; min < n; min += process_max, max += process_max) {
  //do something
}
```

Or do you actually have a list of objects that you need to split into sublists?
e.g.

```
function split(list, chunkSize) {
  var i, result = [];
  for(i = 0; i < list.length; i += chunkSize) {
    result.push(list.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }
  return result;
}
```